# SignalR groups - filtering handled on client or server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've been reading a decent amount regarding SignalR hubs and groups. In particular, I've noticed that you cannot get a count of the connections in a particular group.

Is the filtering for groups handled on the client or server? If the server, why can't SignalR expose a count? If on the client, is there a way to send messages only to particular clients?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you send a message to a particular group of specific connection, filtering happens on the server (there's no filtering, you're just addressing that one connection or group).

SignalR is based on pub sub so there's no list of connections per se. If you want to keep track of a list of connections then you have to handle the connection and disconnect events and persist them in memory or some persistent storage.

The reason we don't give you a list of connections is because any state we store hurts scaling out across nodes. If we gave you a list of connections, it's a pit of failure, because if you add another web node to your farm, you suddenly have to synchronize state across it. We let you address individual connections or groups via their identifier and that allows us to use the message bus to publish to all subscribers of that identifier.

Comment: So, if I have 10,000 clients and I send to a group that only has 5 in it, the other 9,995 won't receive the message and ignore it then? In order to avoid that wouldn't the server need to know who is in what group?

Comment: *So, if I have 10,000 clients and I send to a group that only has 5 in it, the other 9,995 won't receive the message and ignore it then?*


Correct, they won't receive it.


*In order to avoid that wouldn't the server need to know who is in what group?*


Nope, connection state (like groups) is round tripped with the connection itself.

Comment: If the group membership is given to me by the client, is it secure, and unmodifiable? (E.g.  Group `Classified` vs `Secret`)

Comment: @LamonteCristo yes, it is encrypted and signed by the server